# Dev 501 assignment

Tags: certification, dev501

I have passed the Dev501 1st stage exam. I need to take programming 
assignment next. I want to know whether I have to design the data model and relationship everything or they will provide data model and relationship between them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: They would provide you a complete document with requirement and set of rules. So, you will know.

Comment: @NagaChandra : Could you please let me know what are all the resources you are used while preparing for Dev501.

Comment: @sunny Apex developer guide,visualforce developer guide,migration tool,development cycle pdf. you should read document completely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Congratulations!! Datamodel will already be designed and ready along with relationships before hand. You will be asked to develop couple of business functionalities with all the details given in the assignment. It may include triggers, classes, vf pages.Good Luck!